# Fetching data without using query alloy framework

Tags: titanium-alloy

i just want to fetch data from sql without using query.
if i use query I'm getting data successfully but i don't want to use it.

This is what i am trying but i don't know where i am doing wrong.

```
    function showPerson(event) {
        var selectedPerson = event.source;
        var recoverDatabase = Alloy.createCollection("persons");;
        alert("Starting fetching data");
        recoverDatabase.fetch({'name': selectedPerson.title });
        // recoverDatabase.fetch({query:"SELECT * FROM persons WHERE name = '" + selectedPerson.title + "'" });
        alert("Successfully retrive data");
        alert(recoverDatabase.get('name'));
        alert(recoverDatabase.get('Age'));
    }
```

i am not getting an error just empty values.
Thanks

**EDIT**
persons.js

```
exports.definition = {
    config: {
        columns: {
            "id"        : "int",
            "name"      : "text",
            "email"     : "text",
            "age"       : "int",
            "address"   : "text",
            "sex"       : "text"
        },
        adapter: {
            type: "sql",
            collection_name: "persons"
        }
    },
    extendModel: function(Model) {
        _.extend(Model.prototype, {
            // extended functions and properties go here
        });

        return Model;
    },
    extendCollection: function(Collection) {
        _.extend(Collection.prototype, {
            // extended functions and properties go here
        });

        return Collection;
    }
};
```

Comment: post your model for Persons please

Comment: possible duplicate of [Filtering a collection in Titanium Alloy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18347533/filtering-a-collection-in-titanium-alloy)

Comment: @phil person.js added

Comment: check aaron's answer in the issue in the comment above, that should sort you out.